# .increment vs += 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, increment

I have a Picture model that contains a variable for a view count (integer).
The view count is incremented by +1 every time someone views the Picture object.

In getting this done, what is the difference between

```
   @picture.view_count += 1
   @picture.save
```

and

```
   @picture.increment(:view_count, 1)
```

also if i use increment, is .save necessary?

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be `@picture.increment(:view_count, 1)`?

Comment: Be aware of concurrency!! Your both solutions are not safe in this case! Imagine two users run the code at the same time. Both work with the same  `view_count` value. Then second user overwrites the value of the first user on save and the final count is one less than expected.
You should use `increment_counter` to avoid this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The source of `increment` is below, which initializes attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by (default is 1), it does not do save, so `.save` is still necessary.

```
def increment(attribute, by = 1)
  self[attribute] ||= 0
  self[attribute] += by
  self
end
```

Comment: or you can use `increment!` method if you don't want to save it manually

Comment: This is a bit dated, new method is increment_counter

Comment: do you think this increment thing could be scoped with a relation ? post has_many images, the image model having a position attribute that would require to be incremented

Comment: @timroman method increment_counter works on Model class, if you have a record you just call 'increment' on it to increment the value by 1.

Answer (score 34):

I often use `counter_cache` and `increment_counter` in that case.

like this:

```
Picture.increment_counter(:view_count, @picture.id)
```

This way is more simple and faster than self-made method.

Incidentally, ActiveRecord::CounterCache has also `decrement_counter`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This is the best answer, because it takes care of concurrency.

Answer (score 5):

You should use counter_cache. counter_cache helps you increment number of records automaticaly.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
end

class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture, counter_cache: true
end
```

pictures table needs column with name views_count, or you can use your own name for this column, for example:

```
belongs_to :picture, counter_cache: :number_of_views
```

But I recommend you to use default name for counter_cache column which is views_count.

Comment: that'd require a model hence a table ? or could it be "abstracted" ?